# Getting a value from an object

Tags: php

```
<?
var_dump($params); output is this:
?>

object(Cart)#20 (40) {
["id"]=>
 int(117)
 ["id_address_invoice"]=>
 string(2) "18"
 ["id_currency"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id_customer"]=>
  string(6) "120883"
  ["id_guest"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["id_lang"]=>..........
```

How do I get the "id_customer" from the object above?

I`ve tried:

```
$params->cart->id_customer
```

but it is wrong.

Comment: `->cart` is wrong. the object is an object of CLASS `Cart`, but `cart` is not part of the hierarchy. `$params->id_customer` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

$params is the cart object, you don't need to specify it in your accessor:

try

```
$params->id_customer
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Try without `->cart` :

```php
$params->id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have class Cart which includes some of variables. Look in example and you understand.

```
class Cart{

      public $id = 117;  
      public $id_address_invoice = 18;
      public $id_currency = 1;
      public $id_customer = 18;

    }

    $param = new cart();

    var_dump($param);
    var_dump($param->id);
    var_dump($param->id_customer);
```

Result:

```
  object(Cart)#1 (4) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(117)
  ["id_address_invoice"]=>
  int(18)
  ["id_currency"]=>
  int(1)
  ["id_customer"]=>
  int(18)
}
int(117) //$id
int(18) //id_customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the class Cart?? please paste the code of the class.

Maybe exist a method getId_Costumer();

Search in the class the methods get or similar

```
public function getId_Costumer()
{
 return this->id_customer;
}
```